# Elastic Beanstalk app versions max limit reached, how to deploy future app versions, how to backup older versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have 4 applications on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and the total sum of our app versions has recently reached the 1000 limit in the zone so we are trying to figure out what to do. Obviously we want to still be able to deploy new versions but in the mean time we want to make sure we can recover older versions.

What are some best strategies to limit the app versions while still allowing future recoveries reliably?

I have considered using the life cycle policy and maybe store the backups in S3 as IA class.

But since I do not have a lot of experience with AWS yet I'm not sure of the industrial standards and best practices on this. (e.g. how to configure life cycle policy correctly, how to properly store backups and recover them in S3)

Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: They are zip archives, correct (our PHP beanstalk is just zips)?  Just create a private S3 bucket (using IAM to control access), download the archives, upload to the S3 bucket, delete them from beanstalk.  You do want to keep recent versions in beanstalk so you can easily revert if an update goes wrong.

Comment: Yes they are AdonisJS backend applications and the source of each version is a zip file. So you mean download all the sources of each app version manually and upload all the zip files to a private S3 bucket?

Comment: In the AWS  beanstalk console, when you download an app version from the versions list you get back the zip that you uploaded to deploy.  There might be a CLI call for this too, but we upload a zip to deploy, and just upload that same zip to our source code bucket.  At least for PHP, there's nothing special about the app versions in the beanstalk list, it's just a set of zips plus the text strings you chose for the display version